# Print the values of torch.data.dataset object

Tags: python, pytorch

I have made my pandas dataframe `X_train` into `z` tensor but the output is

```
user_id=torchtext.data.RawField()
fields=[('user_id',user_id)]
from torchtext.data import Dataset,Example
z=torchtext.data.Dataset(X_train.user_id,fields)
print(len(z))
print(z)
```

Ouput is:

```
426018
<torchtext.data.dataset.Dataset object at 0x7feffb6a8f98>
```

How should I print the actual data in my variable object z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could `print(list(torch.utils.data.DataLoader()))` be what you're looking for?

```
DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, sampler=None,
           batch_sampler=None, num_workers=0, collate_fn=None,
           pin_memory=False, drop_last=False, timeout=0,
           worker_init_fn=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a range eg. print(z[:]) for all or print(z[:5]) for the first five.